# Any idea how to remove these old Kohler tub knobs?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, plumbing-fixture, knobs

The house was built in 1980 and the bathroom has been untouched since. I’m looking to replace the spout and knobs but can not figure out how to get the knobs off as I don’t see any holes around to loosen the knobs. The spout does have a hole to loosen to remove. [image]